# Bezier curves in As3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bezier

Am i right in thinking that from the Flash GUI you can only draw Cubic Bezier Curves, and from Actionscript you can only draw Quadratic Bezier Curves ? Really?

This seems, well.. im sure it cant be.. It would be crazy if i had to write a Quadratic Bezier drawing app to work out some point co-ordinates.

Comment: in addition to the answer you've got, if you're interested in more bezier math in actionscript, although outdated, this article is pretty good: http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/articles/cubic_bezier_in_flash.htm

Comment: Thanks, i guess i'll have to do this. If i just had a graphics app that could draw quadratics (so i could design the shape of the curve and control point positions) i wouldn't have to.

Comment: It's up to you and your requirements how you implement the curves. You could draw quadratic, cubic (using @divillysausages's handy resources) or other curves(hermite,cardinal, etc.) http://algorithmist.wordpress.com/tag/hermite-curve/ ...It might be worth having a look at Degrafa as well http://degrafa.org/

Comment: @George Implementing Quadratic on-top of Actionscript's Cubic seems non-trivial (at least with any degree of accuracy). The alternative, implementing a rasterizer in AS seems non-optimal.

Comment: With actionscript's curveTo you can draw Quadratic curves, with the code from farmcode or Paul Tondeur listed bellow, you can draw Cubic curves. What is your end goal ? If getting coordinates from a drawing a designer made for example, you could build a drawing tool, or you could script the tool the designer is using to get an output in a format that suits you.

Comment: Doh, i have an inability to get Quadratic / Cubic the right way round (i find it easier to think in terms of Postscript / TrueType). The goal is to draw filled polygons for which i know the Cubic coords (think glyphs in a typeface)

Comment: In that case, you could make your type in Illustrator, convert it to paths and export that path data to something you could use in actionscript (like svg or fxg) to get the Cubic coords and draw them if needed. Would something like this work for you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the drawing API, then you can only draw Quadratic Bezier Curves using the curveTo() function.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#curveTo()

For proper bezier curves, it's not that hard, but you'll have to do it yourself. Some quick links with source code that I found: 
http://www.paultondeur.com/2008/03/09/drawing-a-cubic-bezier-curve-using-actionscript-3/

http://www.farmcode.org/post/2009/07/06/Fast-2D-Bezier-Library-for-ActionScript-3.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it's not that this is a bad answer, i just can't believe that this is the answer.

Comment: @fakeAccount22 That is the answer :)

Comment: After trying so hard not to do so, i see i managed to mix up quadratic and cubic. I have edited the question. Sorry that this makes your answer look not as helpful. I appreciate you taking the time to answer

Answer (score 4):

Actually from Flash Player 11, released yesterday, the Drawing API supports Cubic Bezier curves:

(amongst other improvements and additions on this major release...)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/whats-new-flash-player11.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a great post to draw Cubic Bezier curves in ActionScript using the fl.motion.BezierSegment class:

http://www.eleqtriq.com/2010/04/cubic-bezier-in-flash/

It's awesome - I created a complete curve with multiple segments with a fraction of the code and classes you need for most of the other links on this page:

```
var resolution  :uint       = 50;
var step        :Number     = 1/resolution;

function drawCurve(p0:Point, c0:Point, c1:Point, p1:Point)
{
    var bezier  :BezierSegment  = new BezierSegment(p0, c0, c1, p1);
    var t       :Number         = 0;
    while (t <= 1)
    {
        var pt:Point = bezier.getValue(t);
        with (graphics)
        {
            lineStyle(0.1, 0x00FFFF);
            t == 0
                ? moveTo(pt.x, pt.y)
                : lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
        }
        t+=step;
    }   
    pt = bezier.getValue(1);
    graphics.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);    
}
```

It's a really great post!